# How to call the next page after button login clicked in XDK

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

In my login script when the username and password are both correct it must go to the next page (main/menu page) of the intel XDK.
My problem is how or what code can I use to call the next page whenever the username and password is correct (login successful)?

```
function validateForm() {
    var formUsername = document.forms.login.username.value;
    var formPassword = document.forms.login.password.value;
    var MINLENGTH = 5;

    // Validate username and password
    if (formUsername === null || formUsername === "") {
        alert("Username must be filled out");
    }
    else if (formPassword === null || formPassword === "") {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
    }
    else if (formUsername.length < MINLENGTH || formPassword.length < MINLENGTH) {
        alert("The minimum length of username and password at least " + MINLENGTH);
    }
    else if(formUsername == 'admin' && formPassword == 'admin'){
        alert('welcome');
        //this is where should i put the code to go at the next page of the XDK API. 
        return;
    }        
    alert("Login failed!!!");
}
```

Comment: IntelXDK is bundled free software that allows you to turn simple web apps (built in CSS, JS, and HTML) into hybrid phone applications. With that in mind, you would navigate to the "main menu" or "main page" as you would in a website (which could be different, especially if you're using ionic, or a similar framework)

Basically, we would need more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

got it guys..

it will be.. like this ..

```
else if(formUsername == 'admin' && formPassword == 'admin'){
    alert('welcome');
    activated_page("#menu");
    return;
}
```